# Splitting a string on comma and printing the results

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I am using the following code to split a string and retrieve them:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
      Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String = "a,bc,def,ghij,klmno"
    Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim part As String

    For Each part In parts
        MsgBox(part(0))
    Next

End Sub
```

But the message box shows only the first character in each splitted `string (a,b,d,g,k)`.

I want to show only the first word, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from your question, but if you want only the **first word** in your array of strings then no need to loop over it

```
 Dim firstWord = parts(0)
 Console.WriteLine(firstWord) ' Should print `a` from your text sample

 ' or simply
 Console.WriteLine(parts(0)) 

 ' and the second word is     
 Console.WriteLine(parts(1))  ' prints `bc`
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have each part - just display it:

```
For Each part In parts
  MsgBox(part)
Next
```

`part(0)` will return the first item in the character collection that is a string.

If you want a specific index into the returned string array (as suggested by your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654707/splitting-a-string-on-comma-and-printing-the-results/14654714#comment20479230_14654714)), just access it directly:

```
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})
Dim firstPart As String = parts(0)
Dim thirdPart As String = parts(2)
```

Comment: But I want only first part or second part or third part as I want to choose.

Comment: @SamuelMedhat - You didn't specify that in your question. In such a case, why `For Each` over the `parts` at all? Just access the ones you want directly - `parts(0)` for first, `parts(2)` for third (note I am using `parts`, not `part`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to show `part` not `part(0)`

```
For Each part In parts

     MsgBox(part)
    Next
```