# vb.net regex - capture text between comms

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to extract the first three columns from these two lines of text.

```
A,Frequency,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,94.75 mHz,20,WholeTrace,
A,True RMS,1.404 V,1.403 V,1.404 V,1.403 V,232.6 æV,20,WholeTrace,
```

So what I would like displayed (extracted) form the above string is:

```
1.005 kHz
1.404 V
```

I found this post [Regex exclusive capture between strings (VB.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928957/regex-exclusive-capture-between-strings-vb-net)

Which is seemingly doing something very similar, so I tried to modify that regex, however I am failing dismally (not least of all because I am really struggling to understand regular expressions!).

For mine, I tried

```
cy,\s+(\d+)\s+Hz\s+
```

But that doesn't work.

Could someone kindly help please?

This is in vb.net (VS 2013)

Comment: Split with `,` and get  the item you need

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by split! Where would I put the extra , ? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654707/splitting-a-string-on-comma-and-printing-the-results. Just split the text into lines first if you have the string with multiple *lines*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function:

```
Dim value As String = Split("A,Frequency,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,1.005 kHz,94.75 mHz,20,WholeTrace,", ",")(2)
```

Comment: Thank you hjpotter92 and Wiktor Stribiżew. I learnt something more about VB today (the split function). :-)